# SFTP transfer using WinSCP works on /command but fails on /script

Tags: file-upload, ssis, sftp, winscp, ftps

I am trying to upload a file using WinSCP to a remote SFTP server. When I use the `/command` it works but when I use the same arguments in a script file using `/script` argument, it fails. Below is the cmd screenshot of `/command` argument working.

```
c:\winscp>WinSCP.com /command "open ftps://user:pass@sf-ftp.ebiaas.com/" "put filename.xml" "exit"
Connecting to sf-ftp.ebiaas.com:990 ...
TLS connection established. Waiting for welcome message...
Connected
Starting the session...
Session started.
Active session: [1] user@sf-ftp.ebiaas.com
filename.xml         |           7 KB |   33.6 KB/s | binary | 100%
```

But when I do the same using `/script`, it fails.

```
c:\winscp>WinSCP.com /script="C:\Development\UploadData.txt" /log=log.txt
Connecting to sf-ftp.ebiaas.com:990 ...
TLS connection established. Waiting for welcome message...
Access denied.
Authentication failed.
```

The script file UploadData.txt contents are:

```
open ftps://user:pass@sf-ftp.ebiaas.com/
put filename.xml
exit
```

I am not sure if I am missing something or using the WinSCP client in a wrong way. I read [here](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_scheduler) but it just says the access is denied if files on mapped drive fails. But then it should have failed in both the scenarios. There is another post [here](https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13817) but not sure if that is same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable logging in both scripts using `/log=c:\path\to\log.log` switch. Also enable password logging with `/loglevel=*` switch.

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#logging

And compare both log files to find what's causing the difference.